# Instantiate object on position in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

What is the code when you want to instantiate an object (for example a bullet) on a certian position on screen? I've tried it myself and searched on the internet but there are no good examples or basic Xcode tutorials that explain this. I don't use Cocos2d. Help is much appreciated :) Thanks in advance!

```
//
//  CoreViewController.m
//  Core
//
//  Created by user on 29-04-11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CoreViewController.h"

@implementation CoreViewController

@synthesize ship;
@synthesize bullet;


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == ship){

        //ship
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        ship.center = location;
    }

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == ship){

        //bullet
       // CGPoint blltPos = bullet.center;
        CGPoint shpPos = ship.center;
      //  blltPos.x = blltPos.x += 3;
       // bullet.center = blltPos;

        UIImage *bulletImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet.png"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bulletImage];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(shpPos.x, shpPos.y, 60, 60);
    }


}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using UIKit:

1. Create a `UIImageView` that contains a `UIImage` of the bullet.
2. Set the frame of the `UIImageView` to be the location you want (offset to the center) and the size of the image.

Quick example:

```
UIImage *bulletImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bulletImage];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xLoc, yLoc, bulletImage.size.width, bulletImage.size.height);
```

Comment: Hey Mark! Sorry for the late respond. But I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Could you please look at my script I included above to see if something is wrong?

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are adding the imageView to any parent view.

Comment: Could you please explain this? I'm a noob with Xcode and I followed some tutorials but I just can't wrap this around my finger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already figured it out, but to add the new UIImageView to a parent view, probably(?) the CoreViewController, you'll have to do something like this after you've done what Mark wrote:

```
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

or

```
[self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```

In the latter example you decides its z-position (atIndex) of the subviews, i.e if you want it to be in front or behind other subviews.